# PowerShell commands, what does -r and -p mean? What is the difference between cp -r and cp -recurse

Tags: powershell, cp

I am learning how to use PowerShell and and am looking for a list that explains the commands. I found [this list](http://ss64.com/ps/) but it does not have the specific commands that I am looking for.

My question is: What is the difference between `cp -r` and `cp -recurse`?

Also, it would be nice to know what some of the commands stand for, it would help me to remember them. What does these command actually stand for (the question is not what they do, but what the letter means)?

```
-r 
-p
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shorter versions of powershell cmdlet parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262802/shorter-versions-of-powershell-cmdlet-parameters)

Answer (score 3):

Nothing.  They're identical.

PowerShell only cares about *unambiguous* parameter names.  `-r` is enough to unambiguously mean `-Recurse`.  Indeed, if you type `cp -r` and then hit the tab key, it'll autocomplete to `-Recurse`.

Try this:

```
ls -f
```

You'll get an error that the parameter is ambiguous.  PowerShell cant tell if you mean `-Force` or `-Filter`.  You'd have to type this:

```
ls -fo
```

And now you obviously mean `-Force`.

Comment: Maybe not *obviously*, since i and o are right next to each other on a qwerty keyboard :)

Comment: @Default Hey, as far as the computer knows, humans always type with 100% accuracy!

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.

PowerShell lets you use the shortest non-ambiguous names for a parameter. So because there is no other parameter that starts with `r`, `-r` is taken to mean `-recurse`.

Use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to let powershell expand it for you.